# Cookies not sent in cross-origin jquery ajax request when custom header set

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cors

We are making an ajax request from our main domain to a subdomain (cross-origin) using jQuery.  We have CORS set up, and everything is working until we try to send a custom header with the request.  If a custom header is set on the request, then our session cookies are no longer sent with the request.

jQuery version : 2.1.4

Our origin domain: http://example.com

Our session cookies are set up for subdomain use, using `domain : .example.com` in the cookie options.

CORS headers sent with response from subdomain:

```
 Access-Control-Allow-Origin : http://example.com
 Access-Control-Allow-Credentials : true
 Access-Control-Allow-Headers : Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, X-OurCustomHeader
```

This request **works fine** (session cookie is sent with request) :

```
 jQuery.ajax({
       url: 'http://sub.example.com/someajaxroute',
       xhrFields: { withCredentials: true },
 }
```

This request (with custom header) **does not work** (session cookie is not sent):

```
 jQuery.ajax({
       url: 'http://sub.example.com/someajaxroute',
       xhrFields: { withCredentials: true },
       headers : { 'X-OurCustomHeader' : 'xxx'}
 }
```

*Does anyone know why jQuery/browser is not sending the cookies in the second example?*

---

PS. I know there are a lot of jquery CORS questions on stackoverflow.  I have looked through them extensively, and cannot find one that addresses this exact problem.  **I ask that you please only mark as duplicate if you find a question that matches this exact problem.**  Thank you.

Comment: I'm no Ajax expert, but have you tried using `beforeSend` to set your custom headers instead of using `headers`?

Comment: By setting custom headers, your request becomes more than a "simple" request, meaning it will require properly handling the preflight request. Is your server receiving a preflight request? The preflight request wouldn't contain the cookies. the request method would be `OPTIONS` instead of `GET` for a preflight request. If the preflight fails, the actual request wouldn't be sent.

Comment: @M.Doye - thanks, tried that, but no difference

Comment: @KevinB - Ah right.  I was assuming the OPTIONS preflight stuff was already happening in the (working) first case.  That sounds like the prime suspect then.  Thanks. I'll investigate and report back.

Comment: @UpTheCreek It might have been, depending on browser. some browsers seem to interpret the spec in this case differently than others. The browser console (or fiddler2) will shed light on this.

Answer (score 1):

So it turns out (as @KevinB suggested) that it's an issue with the way that preflight OPTIONS are being processed on our server, and nothing to do with the client.  Thanks Kevin.